# bool does not contain a definition for ToList()

Tags: c#, contains

> CS1061 'bool' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'bool' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

So I am making here a search code to find 2 files named "Withdrawal" and Payment but not containing.XXXX wherein XXXX is HHmm (time). What probably the best thing to do because I am having an error with this ( I am not a developer just trying and pasting what I've searched)

```
           string FolderPath = @"C:\Test";
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(FolderPath);

            var files = di.EnumerateFiles("*.txt")
           .Where(s => s.Name.Contains("Withdrawal"+"payment")
            || !s.Name.Contains("."+DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmm")).ToList());

            var Currentfile1 = files[0].FullName;         
            var Currentfile2 = files[1].FullName;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, What error raised ?! can you add the error to question?!

Comment: I haave this error highlighting my "ToList" to be honest I dont understand much of this I just know how it works.

error message is : Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'bool' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'bool' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) WindowsFormsApplication5 C:\Users\IT-Support\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication5\WindowsFormsApplication5\Form1.cs 30 Active

Comment: you used `.ToList()` in a bad place

Comment: You might be better off using a utility called SearchMyFiles by Nir Sofer. It can do all that you ask without code

Comment: I don't think the specification of what you want in your question is quite clear enough to give a definitive answer but the answer you've accepted as correct doesn't seem to do what I would guess you want?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you used `.ToList()` in a bad place, just update your code as below for resolving your error:

```
var files = di.EnumerateFiles("*.txt")
           .Where(s => s.Name.Contains("Withdrawal"+"payment") || 
           !s.Name.Contains("."+DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmm")))
           .ToList();
```

Comment: Great it works! Thank you so much .. am I getting there for searching 2 files? haha because having this thing for a week now its so hard for me to do such thing. But thank you so much!